# Why is my C++ Game of Life not working properly?

Tags: c++, conways-game-of-life

This compiles and runs okay, but the results are totally different from what they should be.

I've snipped irrelavent code:

```
bool grid[1280][1024]; // hardcoded to my screen res for now

for (int x = 0; x<1280; x++)     //init grid to false
{
    for (int y = 0; y<1024; y++)
    {
        grid[x][y] = false;
    }
}

grid[320][120] = true; // add a simple pattern
grid[320][121] = true;
grid[320][122] = true;
grid[320][123] = true;
grid[320][124] = true;
grid[320][125] = true;
grid[320][126] = true;
grid[320][127] = true;
grid[320][128] = true;

// [snipped]

for (int x = 1; x< (1280 - 1); x++)
{
    for (int y = 1; y< (1024 - 1); y++)
    {
        int n = 0; // neighbours
        if (grid[x-1][y-1]) n++; // top left
        if (grid[x][y-1])   n++; // top middle
        if (grid[x+1][y-1]) n++; // top right

        if (grid[x-1][y])   n++; // left
        if (grid[x+1][y])   n++; // right

        if (grid[x-1][y+1]) n++; // bottom left
        if (grid[x][y+1])   n++; // bottom middle
        if (grid[x+1][y+1]) n++; // bottom right


        if (grid[x][y]) // current cell is on
        {
            SetPixel(screen, x, y, on); // drawing function

            if (n < 2) grid[x][y] = false; // die. :(
            if (n > 3) grid[x][y] = false; // die. :(
            // otherwise (2 or 3), survive. :)

        }
        else // current cell is off
        {
            SetPixel(screen, x, y, off); // drawing function

            if (n == 3) grid[x][y] = true; // IT'S ALIVE!!!
        }



    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, it doesn't work because you haven't separated each cell's results, i.e., if grid[0][0] dies, then this will be immediately reflected on grid[1][0]'s life or death, which is not how Game of Life works. Secondly, it doesn't work because you don't appear to have run the game more than one iteration.

Comment: oooh damn. I think I have to create a duplicate of the array each turn then, and write the results to the duplicate, and overwrite the original with the duplicate at the start of each turn. Am I right? I don't get your second comment though, how have I run it more than one iteration?

Comment: You don't have to overwrite the original array each time. Just toggle the current array in each iteration. The "other" array is always the next current array.

Comment: @Dataflashsabot: You haven't run it more than one iteration. That's the problem. The Game of Life runs forever, not just once.

Comment: @Dialecticus: If you update cells in raster-scan order, you only need a 1280x1 array to store updates, not a full-blown 1280x1024...

Comment: @DeadMG everything after the snip is in a loop. Sorry, thought that was clear at the time :)

Comment: @Data: The reason I didn't find it clear is because it's not indented further - it's indented like it's at the first scope level.

Comment: Ah, whoops. It's indented in the actual code, of course, that was an editing error.