# The second generation is bugged (C, Conways Game of Life)

Tags: c, conways-game-of-life

Hey so my problem is that the when I go run this code and choose to "Zufallstand generieren" (Generate random state) and then type in the "Prozentualer Anteil lebender Zellen" (Percentage of living cells) and then "Schrittweise Animation" or "Fließende Animation" (Step-by-step animation/Flowing animation) the second generation is absolute trash it does not match the first generation in one thing.

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string.h>

#pragma warning (disable: 4996)

#define MAX_ROWS 30
#define MAX_COLS 20

typedef struct {
    char data[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLS];
    int rows;
    int cols;
} Matrix;

char neighbor_count(Matrix *m, int row, int col) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = row - 1; i <= row + 1; i++) {
        if (i < 0 || i >= m->rows) {
            continue;
        }
        for (int j = col - 1; j <= col + 1; j++) {
            if (j < 0 || j >= m->cols) {
                continue;
            }
            if (m->data[i][j] == '*' && (i != row || j != col)) {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}

void check_cell(Matrix *m, int row, int col) {
    char neighbors_count = neighbor_count(m, row, col);
    char current_cell = m->data[row][col];

    if (neighbors_count < 2) { //Die Zelle stirbt an Vereinsamung
        m->data[row][col] = ' ';
    }
    else if (neighbors_count > 3 && current_cell == '*') { //Die Zelle stirbt an Übervölkerung
        m->data[row][col] = ' ';
    }
    else if (neighbors_count == 3 && current_cell == ' ') { //Aus der toten Zelle wird eine neue lebende Zelle
        m->data[row][col] = '*';
    }
    else if (neighbors_count == 2 || neighbors_count == 3) { //Die Zelle lebt weiter
        m->data[row][col] = '*';
    }
}

void load_from_file(Matrix *m, const char *filename) {
    FILE *f = fopen(filename, "r");

    if (f == NULL) {
        printf("File not found\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    int row_idx = 0;
    char ch;
    while ((ch = fgetc(f)) != EOF && row_idx < MAX_ROWS) {
        if (ch == '\n') {
            row_idx++;
            continue;
        }
#
        m->data[row_idx][m->cols] = ch;
        m->cols++;
    }
    m->rows = row_idx;
    fclose(f);
}

void randomize(Matrix *m, int percent) {
    memset(m->data, (int)' ', MAX_COLS * MAX_ROWS);
    m->rows = MAX_ROWS;
    m->cols = MAX_COLS;
    int cells = (m->rows * m->cols) * (percent / 100.0f);
    srand(time(NULL));
    while (cells > 0) {
        int row = rand() % m->rows;
        int col = rand() % m->cols;
        if (m->data[row][col] == ' ') {
            m->data[row][col] = '*';
            cells--;
        }
    }
}

void print_matrix(Matrix *m) {
    for (int i = 0; i < m->rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m->cols; j++) {
            printf("%c", m->data[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void step(Matrix *m) {
    Matrix m_tmp = *m;
    for (int i = 0; i < m->rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m->cols; j++) {
            check_cell(&m_tmp, i, j);
        }
    }
    *m = m_tmp;
}

int main() {
    Matrix m;

    // Menü zur Auswahl des Startzustands
    printf("1. Aus Datei laden\n");
    printf("2. Zufallszustand generieren\n");
    int selection;
    scanf("%d", &selection);

    switch (selection) {
    case 1: // Aus Datei laden
    {
        char  filename[20];
        printf("Bitte Dateinamen angeben: ");
        scanf("%s", filename);
        load_from_file(&m, filename);
        break;
    }
    case 2: // Zufallszustand generieren
    {
        int percent;
        printf("Prozentualer Anteil an lebenden Zellen: ");
        scanf("%d%%", &percent);
        randomize(&m, percent);
        break;
    }
    default:
        printf("Ungültige Eingabe\n");
        return 0;
    }

    // Menü zur Auswahl der Animation
    printf("1. Schrittweise Animation\n");
    printf("2. Fließende Animation\n");
    scanf("%d", &selection);
    switch (selection) {
    case 1: // Schrittweise Animation
        while (1) {
            print_matrix(&m);
            step(&m);
            getchar();

        }
        break;
    case 2: // Fließende Animation6
        while (1) {
            print_matrix(&m);
            step(&m);
            Sleep(2000);
        }
        break;
    default:
        printf("Ungültige Eingabe\n");
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I tried to change the how the matrix works but without any success.

Comment: You cannot change the elements one-by-one sequentially. You need to change them all "at the same time" (probably with the help of a copy of the data)

Comment: @pmg how can i do it??

Comment: The Game of Life is processed one board at a time, right now you're looping over the cells and changing them, thus changing the number of neighbors for each sell. You have to iterate over a copy of the matrix and create a new one for the next iteration.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my C++ Game of Life not working properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4004049/why-is-my-c-game-of-life-not-working-properly)

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal can you give me an example

Comment: @trincot no my code is in c not c++

Comment: That is not the essence. The essence is that it is the same problem with the same solution. The mistake is made in many programming languages alike and the solution is as already commented above.

Comment: The line `Matrix m_tmp = *m` should be replaced by something which actually _copies_ the matrix and doesn't just point to the same one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have mentioned, you are modifying the *current* matrix. You need to have a copy.

Ironically, your `step` function makes a copy. But, it still passes only *one* pointer to `check_cell`.

`check_cell` needs to have *two* matrix pointers. One for old/current state and another for new/future state.

Here are the changed functions:

```
void
check_cell(Matrix *mnew, Matrix *mold, int row, int col)
{
    char neighbors_count = neighbor_count(mold, row, col);
    char current_cell = mold->data[row][col];

    do {
        // Die Zelle stirbt an Vereinsamung
        if (neighbors_count < 2) {
            current_cell = ' ';
            break;
        }

        // Die Zelle stirbt an Übervölkerung
        if (neighbors_count > 3 && current_cell == '*') {
            current_cell = ' ';
            break;
        }

        // Aus der toten Zelle wird eine neue lebende Zelle
        if (neighbors_count == 3 && current_cell == ' ') {
            current_cell = '*';
            break;
        }

        // Die Zelle lebt weiter
        if (neighbors_count == 2 || neighbors_count == 3) {
            current_cell = '*';
            break;
        }
    } while (0);

    mnew->data[row][col] = current_cell;
}

void
step(Matrix *m)
{
    Matrix m_tmp = *m;

    for (int i = 0; i < m->rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m->cols; j++)
            check_cell(m, &m_tmp, i, j);
    }
}
```